# beforeEach fails in karma + Mocha with angular 4 upgrade

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-runner, karma-mocha

## Context

I have confirmed "green" builds on the [master branch](https://travis-ci.org/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/builds/220978980) which is using angular-cli 1.0.0 and the old angular2 dependencies. My Objective is to upgrade from angular2 to angular4.

## Post upgrade issue

- The application works
- The unit tests fail in karma using `ng test` and `npm run test` which are equivalent

#### Working configuration

specifically the `package.json` is as follows.

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    ...
}
```

With the following test result 
[`Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 82 of 83 (skipped 1) SUCCESS (5.674 secs / 0.061 secs)`](https://travis-ci.org/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/builds/220978980)

## Angular 4 upgrade fails the tests

When I try to upgrade the angular4 dependencies with a very [specific diff](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/pull/36/files) the application runs successfully, however I get failed/repeated tests for the upgrade like so [`Chromium 53.0.2785 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 127 of 83 (32 FAILED) (skipped 2) (7.521 secs / 0.101 secs)`](https://travis-ci.org/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/builds/220983784)

What I find fascinating about the result is that there are 44 tests run in addition to the number of tests I actually have. It also appears that the only tests that fail are the **duplicate** tests that are running and they fail directly after they succeed. On investigation is seems that these tests would fail if their before each were not run

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 67 of 83 (13 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.11 secs)
      ✔ will raise a houseCreated event
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0) HouseListComponent when valid input is provided (while in create mode) will raise a houseCreated event FAILED
    AssertionError: expected { Object (country, state, ...) } to equal { Object (country, state, ...) }
        at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/housing/components/edit/house-edit.component.spec.ts:69:40 <- src/test.ts:26683:54)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1520:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:88673:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:364:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1519:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1280:43)
        at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/mocha-patch.js:88:0 <- src/test.ts:88521:33)
        at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/mocha-patch.js:140:0 <- src/test.ts:88573:33
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1553:31)
        at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1320:47)
        at drainMicroTaskQueue (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:593:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1748:35)
        at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:464:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1619:25)
        at timer (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:2695:29)
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 68 of 83 (14 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.111 secs)
      ✖ will raise a houseCreated event
```

#### broken configuration

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    ...
}
```

#### Same tests on a different runner

In attempt to identify if the issue was the tests or the runner, I ran the exact same tests with the wallabyjs runner and I get `No failing tests, 82 passing` which is perfectly inline with master using the upgraded angular4 dependencies. This would seem to indicate that the issues is specific to karma and not the tests.

## resources

- [Working master](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/ab031f583acef77e72061ec3d687697aac53a56c)
- [Broken branch](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/23013d3a19c5130e26672ab4d161eafe56fac9c2)

## Errors

There are a number of test errors, however they all seem to be related to `beforeEach`. The test module should not already be instantiated which seems to be a weird side effect from the repeating tests.

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0) car reducer "before each" hook for "will return array removes existing values when state is not empty" FAILED
    Error: Cannot configure the test module when the test module has already been instantiated. Make sure you are not using `inject` before `TestBed.configureTestingModule`.
        at TestBed.Array.concat.TestBed._assertNotInstantiated (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:749:0 <- src/test.ts:25844:19) [ProxyZone]
        at TestBed.Array.concat.TestBed.configureTestingModule (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:671:0 <- src/test.ts:25766:14) [ProxyZone]
        at Function.Array.concat.TestBed.configureTestingModule (webpack:///~/@angular/core/@angular/core/testing.es5.js:576:0 <- src/test.ts:25671:22) [ProxyZone]
        at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/car/reducers/car.reducer.spec.ts:30:12 <- src/test.ts:31440:27) [ProxyZone]
        at ProxyZoneSpec.Array.concat.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:88673:39) [ProxyZone]
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1280:43) [<root> => ProxyZone]
        at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/mocha-patch.js:88:0 <- src/test.ts:88521:33) [<root>]
```

Then after the before each fails then we get more errors regarding the property `call`

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0) car reducer "before each" hook for "will return array removes existing values when state is not empty" FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:398:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1553:31)
        at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:165:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1320:47)
        at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:460:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:1615:38)
        at timer (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:0 <- src/polyfills.ts:2695:29)
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 45 of 83 (8 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.092 secs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple references in the `frameworks` array should be avoided with Karma. Use the `plugins` instead**

This issue around the failing `beforeEach` was actually a red herring and a side effect of the repeating tests. It appears that the life cycle being executed was:

1. `beforeEach`
2. `it('myTest1')` **pass**
3. `it('myTest1')` **fail**
4. `beforeEach`
5. `it('myTest2')` **pass**
6. `it('myTest2')` **fail**

If we stop the tests repeating then the `beforeEach` issue doesn't actually exist. This was digested and demonstrated in a [karma issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2657) which turned out to be user (my) error.

To stop the tests repeating we needed to update the `frameworks` array in the `karma.conf.js` and reduce the number of framework references and use the `plugins` instead which were already referenced.

`frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'sinon-chai', '@angular/cli'],`

becomes

`frameworks: ['mocha', '@angular/cli'],`

## Resolution

Stop the tests repeating and the `beforeEach` will behave as expected. A working commit can be [found here](https://github.com/arranbartish/angular-cli-seed/tree/5a3037117326ee2ecfb8be44e7dbe42db1e6d0fb).